# nesting multiple react applications within a single parent application

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm currently working on a project where a situation has come up that I haven't experienced before and not sure I know the best way to handle it. I am looking to have one parent react application that would handle my navigation (with react-router) throughout the different pages of the app and also the login/authentication.

Then in the same repository I would be looking to have multiple other react applications that would render whenever clicked on the from the navigation menu in the parent application, with the navigation menu always remaining on the page.

Does anyone have any good suggestions on how to accomplish this. Maybe even with only one build process (not a necessity, but a nice to have)

Comment: If they have to remain separate applications, you could try using IFrames.

Comment: If you want everything in the same repository, then I'm not sure what you mean by “other react apps”. You’re really just describing switching between different components based on a link click (which react-router does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after a micro front end.
You could take a look at https://github.com/CanopyTax/single-spa/tree/master/examples
This is a great project with lots of potential. Unfortunately , I haven't been able to use it since my company insists on using create-react-app and version 2 has been problematical when trying to use the library with it.